# When I remove an iframe and reopen it, the height is not calculated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am using jQuery to

1. dynamically create an iframe,
2. hide the page content,
3. append the iframe to a hidden div,
4. calculate the height of the iframe,
5. set the hidden div to have a height which matches the height of the iframe,
6. show the hidden div (`$("#products_container").slideDown())`.

And this all works fine.

And then if you close that product, the iframe is removed and the original page contents come back. All is perfect!

And then if you open a second iframe, it has a height of 0. (This works fine in Chromium; but in Firefox, second and subsequent iframes always have a height of zero.)

The height of the iframe will depend on its content. They have quite simple HTML and reasonably complicated CSS, with min-heights and lots of padding.

I put `sleep(5)` at the top of the PHP code which generates the iframe, just to help me to double-check what’s going on. As expected, the `console.log('URI: ' + uri)` fires immediately, and `console.log('src: ' + this.src); console.log('height: ' + infr_height)` happens after the five-second delay. This means that the iframe *is indeed* loaded before we try to calculate the height.

I’ve tried using `$(infr).load()` instead of `infr.onload`. That makes no difference. I’ve made sure that the `onload` event is set *before* the src is set, and before the iframe is appended to the HTML, to ensure that it is fired correctly. I added `$("iframe").remove()` when the iframe is closed, to ensure that the previous iframe wasn’t hanging around confusing matters.

Nothing I can think of has any effect.

```
page_href = document.location.href;

function open_product(uri, hist) {
    console.log('URI: ' + uri);console.log('URI: ' + uri);
    $('p').slideUp();
    $("#products_container").slideUp();
    var infr = document.createElement('iframe');
    infr.style.border = 'none';
    var infr_height;
    infr.onload = function() {
        var $pc = $("#product_content");
        $pc.css('width', '100%');
        infr_height = $(this).contents().height();
        console.log('src: ' + this.src);
        console.log('height: ' + infr_height); // always zero on second and subsequent loads
        $(this).css('width', '100%');
        $(this).css('height', '100%');
        $pc.height(infr_height);
        $pc.slideDown();
        if (hist) {
            var uri = $(this).contents().find('#canonical').attr('href');
            // I can't get the state to work the way I want it to, so I'll do this
            // with the pathname. Bah!
            history.pushState(null, null, uri);
        }
        var close = document.createElement('img');
        close.src = '/custom/public/styles/gallery/fancybox/button_close.png';
        close.onclick = close_product;
        app.get("product_content").appendChild(close);
        close.style.position = 'absolute';
        close.style.right = '50px';
        close.style.top = '10px';
    };
    infr.src = uri;
    var pc = app.get("product_content");
    pc.appendChild(infr);
    pc.style.position = 'relative';
}

function show_all_prds() {
    var $pc = $("#product_content")
    $pc.slideUp();
    $("iframe").remove();
    $pc.empty();
    $pc.attr('style', '');
    $('p').slideDown();
    $("#products_container").slideDown();
}

function close_product() {
    show_all_prds();
    history.pushState(null, null, page_href);
}

$("a.inlineframe").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    open_product(this.href, true);
});

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    var uri = document.location.toString().split('/');
    var section = uri[3];
    if (section === 'products') {
        var prd = uri[4];
        console.log(prd);
        var open = '/custom/api/product.output.php?name=' + prd;
        open_product(open, false);
    } else {
        show_all_prds();
    }
};
```

Comment: As an incidental, you can also see that my HistoryAPI stuff is working around the fact that I couldn't reliably get a `state` included, so I had to fall back to parsing the URL.

Comment: doesn't the height get automatically set to 0 if the parent it hidden? because the parent's height is also 0 ? Try not hiding the div to see if it's being calculated right

Comment: Commenting out the line `$pc.slideUp()` does seem to have the desired effect, but I'm not sure why. Shouldn't the iframe itself know its own height, independent of the height of the container it's in?